# String list with comma separated values to int list

Tags: c#, list

As part of a larger program I need to convert a string list with comma separated values to an Int list where the information must be arranged in a particular way. In other words, I have this string listA:

```
**ListA(string)**

[0] "4, 0, 7, -1,"  

[1] "0, 1, 7, -1,"  

[2] "7, 1, 6, -1,"
```

That I want to convert into this int ListB:

```
**List B(int)**

 [0]    {int[4]}    

        [0] 4   
        [1] 0   
        [2] 7   
        [3] -1  

 [1]    {int[4]}

        [0] 0   
        [1] 1   
        [2] 7   
        [3] -1
 [2]    {int[4]}


        [0] 7   
        [1] 1   
        [2] 6   
        [3] -1
```

I have been trying to figure out how to do it but I did not manage to get it right.

If you could give me hand I would be grateful!

Many thanks!

Comment: So separate this into different parts - for example, splitting the string by commas, and converting each substring into an int. How far have you got with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using LINQ is more succint but this is another way you could accomplish the same thing just separated out more.

```
var stringList = new List<string>() { "4, 0, 7, -1,", "0, 1, 7, -1,", "7, 1, 6, -1," };
        var intList = new List<int[]>();

        foreach(var str in stringList)
        {
            // Call Trim(',') to remove the trailing commas in your strings
            // Use Split(',') to split string into an array
            var splitStringArray = str.Trim(',').Split(',');

            // Use Parse() to convert the strings as integers and put them into a new int array
            var intArray = new int[]
            {
                int.Parse(splitStringArray[0])
                ,int.Parse(splitStringArray[1])
                ,int.Parse(splitStringArray[2])
                ,int.Parse(splitStringArray[3])
            };

            intList.Add(intArray);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var listB = new List<string>() { "4, 0, 7, -1,", "0, 1, 7, -1,", "7, 1, 6, -1," }
    .Select(
        x => x.TrimEnd(',') //removing last ","
                .Split(',') //splitting string into array by ","
                .Select(int.Parse) //parsing string to int
                .ToList()
    ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily done with LINQ

```
var a = new List<string> {"1, 2, 3, 4", "5, 6, 7, 8"};

List<int[]> b = a.Select(s => s.Split(new [] {", "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(int.Parse).ToArray()).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Just one thing, how could I get rid of the commas?